# Forming a Wright-Fisher loop with "sample()"

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to create a simple loop to generate a Wright-Fisher simulation of genetic drift with the `sample()` function (I'm actually not dead-set on using this function, but, in my naivety, it seems like the right way to go). I know that `sample()` randomly selects values from a vector based on certain probabilities. My goal is to create a system that will keep running making random selections from successive sets. For example, if it takes some original set of values and samples a second set, I'd like the loop to take another random sample from the second set (using the probabilities that were defined earlier).

I'd like to just learn how to do this in a very general way. Therefore, the specific probabilities and elements are arbitrary at this point. The only things that matter are (1) that every element can be repeated and (2) the size of the set must stay constant across generations, per Wright-Fisher. For an example, I've been playing with the following:

```
V <- c(1,1,2,2,2,2)    
sample(V, size=6, replace=TRUE, prob=c(1,1,1,1,1,1))
```

Regrettably, my issue is that I don't have any code to share yet precisely because I'm not sure of how to start writing this kind of loop. I know that `for()` loops are used to repeat a function multiple times, so my guess is to start there. However, from what I've researched about these, it seems that you have to start with a variable (typically i). I don't have any variables in this sampling that seem explicitly obvious; which isn't to say one couldn't be made up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to repeatedly sample from a population with replacement for a total of `iter` iterations, you could use a `for` loop:

```
set.seed(144)  # For reproducibility
population <- init.population
for (iter in seq_len(iter)) {
  population <- sample(population, replace=TRUE)
}
population
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Data:

```
init.population <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2)
iter <- 100
```